# Perl threads to execute a sybase stored proc parallel

Tags: multithreading, perl, sybase

I have written a sybase stored procedure to move data from certain tables[~50] on primary db for given id to archive db. Since it's taking a very long time to archive, I am thinking to execute the same stored procedure in parallel with unique input id for each call.

I manually ran the stored proc twice at same time with different input and it seems to work. Now I want to use Perl threads[maximum 4 threads] and each thread execute the same procedure with different input.

Please advise if this is recommended way or any other efficient way to achieve this. If the experts choice is threads, any pointers or examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you do in Perl does not really matter here: what matters is what happens on the side of the Sybase server. Assuming each client task creates its own connection to the database, then it's all fine and how the client achieved this makes no diff for the Sybase server. But do not use a model where the different client tasks will try to use the same client-server connection as that will never happen in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

No 'answer' per se, but some questions/comments:

Can you quantify `taking a very long time to archive`?  Assuming your archive process consists of a mix of `insert/select` and `delete` operations, do query plans and MDA data show fast, efficient operations?  If you're seeing table scans, sort merges, deferred inserts/deletes, etc ... then it may be worth the effort to address said performance issues.

Can you expand on the comment that running two stored proc invocations at the same time `seems to work`?  Again, any sign of performance issues for the individual proc calls?  Any sign of contention (eg, blocking) between the two proc calls?  If the archival proc isn't designed properly for parallel/concurrent operations (eg, eliminate blocking), then you may not be gaining much by running multiple procs in parallel.

How many engines does your dataserver have, and are you planning on running your archive process during a period of moderate-to-heavy user activity?  If the current archive process runs at/near 100% cpu utilization on a single dataserver engine, then spawning 4 copies of the same process could see your archive process tying up 4 dataserver engines with heavy cpu utilization ... and if your dataserver doesn't have many engines ... combined with moderate-to-heavy user activity at the same time ... you could end up invoking the wrath of your DBA(s) and users.  Net result is that you may need to make sure your archive process hog the dataserver.

One other item to consider, and this may require input from the DBAs ... if you're replicating out of either database (source or archive), increasing the volume of transactions per a given time period could have a negative effect on replication throughput (ie, an increase in replication latency); if replication latency needs to be kept at a minimum, then you may want to rethink your entire archive process from the point of view of spreading out transactional activity enough so as to not have an effect on replication latency (eg, single-threaded archive process that does a few insert/select/delete operations, sleeps a bit, then does another batch, then sleeps, ...).

---

It's been my experience that archive processes are not considered high-priority operations (assuming they're run on a regular basis, and before the source db fills up); this in turn means the archive process is usually designed so that it's efficient while at the same time putting a (relatively) light load on the dataserver (think: running as a trickle in the background) ... ymmv ...

Comment: hi markp,

Please find my answers below
1) I have ? million+ ids to archive. based on my last runs 18k ids to archive
from 58 tables took around 11 hours. As you mentioned i am doing insertfupdate
and deletes. Query plan seems to be good and i am using certain columns in each
table which is having index. so this is not an issue for me. I run all the
queries in a transaction. so any error occurred within the procedure will
rollback the whole transaction for given id.

Comment: 2) I ran the same proc twice with only 10 id's as input for each call. so i am
not sure if running the proc parallely with 10**K** id each will lead to any
type of blocking or performance issues. I will be testing this out tomorrow and
get back.
3) dataserver should have around 20 enignes, but not less for sure. And yes this
archival will be running on weekends with less user activity. running 4 threads
is also a concern for me here.

Comment: 4) There is replication being setup on source db and as you mentioned dba
suggestions have to be gathered on this.
from what i read regarding threads, without careful and proper implementation it
could lead to memory related issues. I cant find any example to achieve my
request in threads. Though it may not work, atleast i want to test it out in QA
and see its performance.
any sample code would be of great help.

Comment: running 4 concurrent processes on a 20-engine dataserver shouldn't be a problem re: dataserver resources; not sure where your memory issues/concerns are coming from, so not able to comment on that; if replication latency becomes an issue, and replication is being used solely for DR, you may want to work with the DBA(s) to run the archive process on both dataservers (primary and replicate/DR) ... DBA could grant `replication_role` to your process, then you need to issue `set replication off` (in each thread) prior to kicking off your archive operations (test to make sure rep disabled)